Executing decorator without invoking the method
I am trying to register methods and functions into express. For example:
@Controller("/api/users/")
export class UserController {

    constructor() {
        console.log("constructor")
    }

    @GET("get/:id")
    public getUser(req: Request, res: Response) {

    }
}

The decorator is as follows:
export function Controller(basePath: string) {
    return function(target: any) {
        const instance = new target();
        const methodList = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype).map(m => target.prototype[m])
        methodList.forEach(method => {
            console.log(method) //<--- What should I put here?
        })
    }
}

export function GET(url: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: String, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const originalMethod = descriptor.value;

        descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
            descriptor.value.url = url
        }
        return descriptor;
    }
}

How do I get the value "get/:id" without invoking getUser function?
The goal is to reference getUser to Express router. So in this case, I want to register getUser(req, res) as express.router.get(basePath + url, method)
I don't know what to put there to replace console.log(method) to register the methods

Your GET function probably needs to temporarily store this information on the class somewhere. This function runs when the class is defined.

Why are you not doing anything with originalMethod? And what is async function (...args: any[]) { descriptor.value.url = url } supposed to achieve, why is it asynchronous?

@Bergi well, I WILL be doing something, just not at this stage. I don't even sure why it should async or not at this point. But the (req,res) that I have to pass should be async.

@Evert yes, I plan to store it at descriptor.value.url. Was that the problem? Let me try to store it at the class.

I would suggest you replace the entire descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) { … }; statement by just descriptor.value.url = url;

The idea is to make your GET decorator store the url with reflect-metadata
By the time @Controller is evaluated, @Get() would have been executed and metadata stored. All you have to do then is to retrieve all stored metadata.
export function Controller(basePath: string) {
    return function(target: any) {
        const instance = new target();
        const methodList = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(target.prototype).map(m => target.prototype[m])
        methodList.forEach(method => {
            const url = Reflect.getOwnMetadata("my-get-url", target.prototype, m)
        })
    }
}

export function GET(url: string) {
    return function (target: any, propertyKey: String, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    Reflect.defineMetadata("my-get-url", url, target, descriptor.propertyKey
    // ...
    }
}


Note that this simple implementation requires extra work if you want to make it working with inheritance.
This is one of the reasons why I created @aspectjs/core.
With aspectjs, you could solve this issue as simple as this:
import {
  AnnotationFactory,
  AnnotationKind,
} from '@aspectjs/common';
import { Aspect, Compile, on, AdviceContext, getWeaver } from '@aspectjs/core';

// Define your annotations
const af = new AnnotationFactory('my-org');
const GET = af.create(AnnotationKind.METHOD, 'GET', (url: string) => {});
const Controller = af.create(AnnotationKind.CLASS, 'Controller', (url: string) => {});

// Create an aspect that registers your controller
@Aspect()
class RegisterExpressControllerAspect {
  @Compile(on.classes.withAnnotations(Controller))
  registerController(ctxt: AdviceContext) {
    
    const get = ctxt.annotations(GET).find({searchParents: true})[0]!;
    const [url] = get.args
    console.log(url)
  }
}

getWeaver().enable(new RegisterExpressControllerAspect())


@Controller("/api/users/")
export class UserController {

    constructor() {
        console.log("constructor")
    }

    @GET("get/:id")
    public getUser(req: Request, res: Response) {

    }
}

